# Showing default image when original image is broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show default image when the main image is broken using the html5 image source set:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 992px)" srcset="main-image.jpg 1x, main-image.jpg 2x">
  <source srcset="main-image.jpg 1x, main-image.jpg.png 2x,">
  <img src="main-image.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='default-image.png;'">
</picture>
```

I am adding on error attribute to handle the default image, but the `img` tag used here as fallback so my default image not appearing.

How do I handle `onerror` attribute in `<source>` tag?

Answer (score -1):

if you getting this type of error first you have to check your image path.
try this code this almost solved the error.

assets1/img/default.jpg';">

Hope your issue will solved using the script.
Thank You

Comment: Yes I was update my code also 

<img src="path_to_original_img/img.png"  alt="Image Name" 
       onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='<?=base_url()?>assets1/img/default.jpg';">